# Clicking on links in emails auto-fill the date, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

So right now I am completely stumped, I am trying to set up an action mailer in a ruby on rails app to autofill the date on my check in form with the date of the missing check in, and have no idea where to start.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
     </head>
 <body>
<p>
  Psssstt! Remember to <%= link_to "check-in for #{@friendly_date}", new_check_in_url %>
</p>
<p> --Team Capacitor
</p>
```

Above is the original email where we have the date, which already leads to the check in form, I just need to know how to autofill the date picker with the `@friendly_date` once the link is clicked.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: It can be done in the form.  Please add the code for your view with the form.  If you have a Javascript datepicker, let us know which one and show the initialization code for it, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can send he date in params of the link

```
  Psssstt! Remember to <%= link_to "check-in for #{@friendly_date}",
 new_check_in_url(autofill_date: @friendly_link) %>
```

Once you have received this in your controller action in `params`, you can use this value to autofill your data